# Extract part of list by reading it in a cyclic manner

Tags: list-manipulation

I have trouble extracting part of a list in a specific order, say, increasingly in a cyclic manner. For example, I have the following list

```
list={0,10,6,-5,-10}
```

and I want to extract, as a new list, its increasing values from its minimum to its maximum, but only read in a cyclic manner, i.e. I want it to return {-10, 0, 10}.

Now, I know that in case the list is given already in increasing order, `Parts[list,n;;m]` does the trick. But for a list with arbitrary order, is there a function that does what I want?

Comment: Can you use something like `NestWhile[RotateLeft, {0, 10, 6, -5, -10}, First[#] != Min[#] &]` as a starting point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ClearAll[f]
f = With[{pos = Ordering[#][[{1, -1}]]}, 
     If[Less @@ pos, #[[Span @@ pos]], Join[#[[pos[[1]] ;;]], #[[;; pos[[2]]]]]]] &;

f@{0, 10, 6, -5, -10}
```

> {-10, 0, 10}

```
f@{0, 10, 6, -10, -5}
```

> {-10, -5, 0, 10}

```
f@{0, -10, 6, -5, 10}
```

> {-10, 6, -5, 10}